# Error message configuring services in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have recently renamed a SharePoint 2010 server and have been experiencing some odd errors.  Mostly the site works but when I try to run the Sharepoint Configuration Wizard or access some Service Account settings under CA, I get error thrown.

After checking the log file I see messages referring to the User Profile Service...

*User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.*

The server has been renamed and added to the domain so the problems may have been caused by either of these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need tell SharePoint that your server has been renamed.

Use powershell:
Rename-SPServer [-Identity]  -Name

Afterwards do an IISRESET

Afterwards you may want to look at your alternate access mappings and such. '

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Yeah, I had renamed the server already and had fixed up AAMs so the issue wasn't with those things.  On top of these errors, the Sharepoint 2010 Configuration Wizard would fail to run as well as I thought I could use this to fix the farm and service accounts.

Comment: ...in the end I recreated the farm.